# Using NEST on ElasticSearch - How do i use a partially populated object as a search criteria

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So I have successfully created my index of "Package" objects and a straight forward text query is working perfectly.

I'd love to know if / how i can use a partially populated object (of type "Package") as the criteria for my search?

Packages looks something like:

```
var packages =  new List<Package> {
            new Package {
                Name = "Maverick",
                TargetBusiness = new Business {
                    Industry = "Retail",
                    BusinessType = BusinessType.Product,
                    LocationType = LocationType.Store
                },
                Description = "Standard package for retail shops"
            },
            new Package {
                Name = "Goose",
                TargetBusiness = new Business {
                    Industry = "Retail",
                    BusinessType = BusinessType.Product,
                    LocationType = LocationType.Online
                },
                Description = "Standard package for ecommerce shops"
            },
            new Package {
                Name = "Viper",
                TargetBusiness = new Business {
                    Industry = "Advertising",
                    BusinessType = BusinessType.Service,
                    LocationType = LocationType.Office
                },
                Description = "Standard package test retail"
            }
        }
```

query currently looks something like:

```
var result = client.Search<Package>(x => x.Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("q=retail"))));
```

But id like to have something like:

```
var result = client.Search<Package>(x => x.Query(q => q.Object(new Package{...etc ...})));
```

I hope I'm making sense :D
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = client.Search<Package>(x => x.Query(q => q.Object(new Package{...etc ...})));
```

Can never work because [Nest](https://github.com/mpdreamz/nest) cannot infer what type of query to use for each property on your object, (i.e term, prefix, wildcard, query_string, etc etc etc).

In your example `q=retail` only works because `elasticsearch` will break the query up into `q OR retail`. You can target fields using regular lucene syntax i.e `targetBusiness.industry:retail`.

In elasticsearch if your querystring is not bound to a field it will by default search in the `_all` field which will have all the terms for all the properties of an object. Which is why if you really have a lot of data turning off `_all` support is usually a really good idea.

[Nest](https://github.com/mpdreamz/nest) doesn't currently have such a functionality where it can take a partially filled object and translate it into an elasticsearch `query_string` query.

Say if this is your query:

```
client.Search<Package>(s=>s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Filter(f=>
        f.Term(p=>p.TargetBusiness.Industry, "Advertising")
        && f.Exists(p=>p.Name)
    )
    .Query(q=>
       q.QueryString(qs=>qs
           .Query("ecommerce")
           .Operator(Operator.and)
       )
    )
)
```

In the above example you'll have to create your own method that gives all the terms to search for in the query string query based on your package.

i.e

```
public string MyPackageQueryString(Package package) 
{
    var myTerms = List<string>();
    myTerms.Add(package.Name);
    if (package.TargetBusiness != null)
    {
        myTerms.Add(package.Industry)
        ....
    }
    ...
    return string.Join(" ", myTerms.Where(t=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)));
}
```

and then

```
client.Search<Package>(s=>s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Filter(f=>
        f.Term(p=>p.TargetBusiness.Industry, "Advertising")
        && f.Exists(p=>p.Name)
    )
    .Query(q=>
       q.QueryString(qs=>qs
           .Query(this.MyPackageQueryString(package))
           .Operator(Operator.or)
       )
    )
)
```

Comment: ok that implies searching every property against every other property right?

Comment: yeah although you can easily replace it with "field:value" syntax, this might be something to add into NEST. I need to let the idea sink in a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

That really helped put me on the right track - in the end that looked like a sort of cross search: Searching every field with every other field which i didn't want.

Ended up (possible incorrectly) going with:

```
return _searchClient.Search<Package>(s => s.Query(q => 
        q.Term("industry", criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.Industry.ToLower()) ||
        q.Term("description", criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.Description.ToLower()) ||
        q.Term("businessType",((int)criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.BusinessType).ToString()) ||
        q.Term("locationType", ((int)criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.LocationType).ToString()) ||
        q.Term("marketSegment", criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.MarketSegment.ToLower()) ||
        q.Term("offer", criteriaPackage.TargetBusiness.Offer.ToLower()))
      ).Documents;
```

Which after a few unit tests seemed to be producing the results i was wanting.